In a real ordered TVS, what additional properties need be added to get "nice" supremums
RESTATED QUESTION
I have simplified my question since it is not getting an answer. Basically, when does the monotone convergence theorem hold in an ordered TVS over $\mathbb R$.
Here is the precise question: If $\left\{ a_{i}\mid i\in I\right\}$  is a descending net in an ordered TVS, meaning $a_{i}\ge a_{j}$ for all $i,j\in I$ with $i\le j$, and if $\inf\left\{ a_{i}\mid i\in I\right\}$  exists, then $a_{i}\longrightarrow\inf\left\{ a_{i}\mid i\in I\right\}$.
Here is an attempt at a proof: Assume wolg $a_{i}\ge 0$.
Let $b=\inf\left\{ a_{i}\mid i\in I\right\}$  then by def of infimum $b\le a_{i}$ for all $i\in I$ and if $c\le a_{i}$ for all $i\in I$ then $c\le b$.
Let U be a nhd of $0$.
Pick an order convex nhd $V\subseteq U$ of $0$. I don't know when this is possible, order convex means if $0\le c\le a\in V$ then $c\in V$.
Pick any $\varepsilon>0$ st $\varepsilon b\in V$ and consider $b\left(1+\varepsilon\right)>b$. There must be a $j\in I$ st $a_{j}<b\left(1+\varepsilon\right)$, otherwise we would have $a_{j}\ge b\left(1+\varepsilon\right)$ for all $j\in I$ so $b\left(1+\varepsilon\right)$ would be a lower bound, but $b\left(1+\varepsilon\right)>b$ contradicting $b$ being the infimum. Pick such a $j\in I$.
Let $i\ge j$ in $I$ be arbitrary then we have $b\le a_{i}\le a_{j}<b\left(1+\varepsilon\right)=b+\varepsilon b$ so subtracting $b$ we get $0\le a_{i}-b<\varepsilon b$ so by the order convexity of V we have $a_{i}-b\in V\subseteq U$.
Therefore, we have shown for any nhd $U$ of $0$ there is a $j\in I$ st  $a_{i}-b\in U$ for all $i\ge j$ in $I$, in other words $a_{i}\longrightarrow b$ as required.
ORIGINAL QUESTION
I am trying to work out what properties I need to be true in an ordered topological vector space (oTVS) over $\mathbb R$ in order to make certain properties the reals have hold in the oTVS. These properties involve infimums and supremums of arbitrary sets.
The property in $\mathbb R$ is:

If $a_i \le c$  for every $i\in I$ then $\sup_{i\in I} a_i \le c$.

In the oTVS, I need to say something like:

Suppose $E$ is a ??? oTVS and $D\subseteq E$ has properties ???.
Given $C\subseteq D$ with properties ??? and  $a_i \in C$  for every
$i\in I$ then $\sup_{i\in I} a_i \in C$.

I may need $E$ to be a vector lattice, and I clearly need some kind of completeness properties. Relevant properties seem to be a solid neighbourhood basis at $0$, where solid means closed inwards.
Other relevant properties seem to be that a set $C$ is order bounded in $D$ iff there are $a,b\in D$ such that $C\subseteq\left[a,b\right]$, and $D$ is order complete iff for all $\varnothing\neq C\subseteq D$, if $C$ is order bounded in $D$ then $\sup C$ and $\inf C$ both exist and are in $D$ (I need them to be in $C$).
I do not know enough to put all the properties together in a coherent way to properly express the oTVS equivalent to the $\mathbb R$ property, or what oTVS properties come into play to make it all work.
Any guidance appreciated.

I'm not sure what you mean by an "ordered" vector space, but surely it should include that if $r < s \in \Bbb R$ and $v$ is vector in the space, then $rv < sv$. If so, then the only examples would be 1-dimensional. The line of $v$ is the set $\Bbb Rv = {r v : r \in \Bbb R}$. What would be the supremum of that line? It cannot be a point of the line, and if you choose some vector $w$ off the line, then $0.5 w < w$ and therefore must be less than some points on the line. $\Bbb R$ is the only ordered field with the supremum property.

You need more assumptions for this to work. Consider the ordered vector space $E$ of all bounded functions from $[0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$ with the topology of uniform convergence. The functions $f_n:x\mapsto x^n$ (with $n\in\mathbb N$) form a decreasing sequence in $E$ whose infimum in $E$ is $0$ and which doesn't converge uniformy to $0$.

Thanks @P.P.Tuong. I think my proof may be valid in an ordered locally convex TVS because I believe then, given the topology is compatible with the order (positive cone closed), there exists a base of order-convex, convex, balanced, and absorbing neighborhoods of the origin (if ChatGPT is to be believed, I am checking). Do you agree?

@MarkKortink No, the counterexample I gave you is already locally convex (and even normable).
